# Getting 500 Internal Server Error when calling /mint_nft NEAR REST API

Tags: nearprotocol

I have cloned this [NEAR REST API SERVER](https://github.com/near-examples/near-api-rest-server) repo into my local system and haven't made any changes to its original code. Only added console logs for debugging purpose. Using its API, I have successfully deployed a contract to testnet account and also called that contract.

But when comes to NFT part, its not working.
I'm calling `/mint_nft` API and getting 500 Internal Server Error.

[image]

It's breaking here:

`let create_token = await token.ViewNFT(tokenId, contract);`

create_token is null.

[image]

---

If I do minting with NEAR CLI, its working fine and I can see that NFT in my testnet wallet..

`near call $ID nft_mint '{"token_id": "02", "receiver_id": "'$ID'", "token_metadata": { "title": "Design #2", "description": "Art Design", "media": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qme7ss3ARVgxv6rXqVPiikMJ8u2NLgmgszg13pYrDKEoiu", "copies": 1}}' --accountId $ID --deposit 0.1`

[image]

---

near-api-server.config.json

```js
{
  "server_host": "localhost",
  "server_port": 9000,
  "rpc_node": "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
  "init_disabled": false,
  "master_account_id": "parimal9.testnet",
  "master_key": "ed25519:2bUSD2v88RiwznraL1ZYtduH2rsJqbrE8K6QT2asnsPnXHc171Qj4khvxFxZqb6AN6zyiZzo4j7f9amooFi7kJX1",
  "nft_contract": "nft.parimal9.testnet"
}
```

---

I have also tried this way but still not working.

[image]

---

```js
server.route({
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/mint_nft',
        handler: async (request) => {
            console.log('\n\n\nMINT_NFT_PAYLOAD:', request.payload);
            let {min, max} = request.payload;

            if (!min || !max) min = max = 0;
            let response = [];

            request = processRequest(request);
            for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
                const tokenId = request.payload.token_id.replace('{inc}', i);
                console.log('tokenId:', tokenId);

                let {account_id, private_key, metadata, contract} = request.payload;

                const tx = await token.MintNFT(
                    tokenId,
                    metadata,
                    contract,
                    account_id,
                    private_key
                );

                if (tx) {
                    if (min === max) {
                        console.log('tokenId:', tokenId);
                        let create_token = await token.ViewNFT(tokenId, contract);
                        console.log('create_token:', create_token, '\n\n\n');
                        create_token.token_id = tokenId;
                        console.log('create_token.token_id:', tokenId, '\n\n\n');
                        response.push({token: create_token, tx: tx});
                    } else {
                        response.push({tx: tx});
                    }
                } else {
                    response.push({text: 'Error. Check backend logs.'});
                }
            }

            return response;
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in the existing repository for `/mint_nft`.

The REST-API implemented doesn't follow the correct format when minting an NFT.
I have created a [PR to address the issue](https://github.com/near-examples/near-api-rest-server/pull/6)

In short, the function call to mint an NFT is missing one argument, `receiver_id`, and the format and name of `metadata` is not correct. It should be `token_metadata: {} // type is object, not string`.

If we change the postData to

```
{
    "token_id": "foo",
    "token_metadata": {
        "media": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qme7ss3ARVgxv6rXqVPiikMJ8u2NLgmgszg13pYrDKEoiu"
    },
    "account_id": "parimal9.testnet",
    "private_key": "yourPrivateKey",
    "contract": "parimal9.testnet"
}
```

and make a few changes to the server code, which you can see in the [PR I made](https://github.com/near-examples/near-api-rest-server/pull/6/files), we should be able to call `/mint_nft` from the server.

Comment: John, Thanks a million. I have made changes in my local code of REST API as per your PR. Its working..

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I used your master key when I was debugging this, so you may have gotten a few NFTs on your testnet account. I recommend editing the question to remove the master key. It's only a testnet account, so it doesn't matter much, but still. If it were a mainnet account, I would have been able to take all your NEAR tokens! D: